# R/ROracle How to get dbListTables from specific SCHEMA

Tags: r, roracle

How to get the list of table names from database for certain scheme?

```
tabellen <- dbListTables(con, all=T)
```

gives all the tables from database, but i would like to specify the scheme. I read in the ROracle package that i can specify scheme like:

```
tabellen <- dbListTables(con, schema="K")
```

However i get an empty character...

when i use sql command:

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER ='K'")
data <- fetch(rs)
```

It works but i get a table, not a list what i would prefer too.. Is there a way to get directly the list of tables? **[SOLVED]** - too much programming..I wrote `scheme` instead of `schema`...Thanks for pointing it out, my bad, sorry for that

**And additionally how i can get the name of columns for certain table which i choosed [NOT SOLVED]**

Thanks for help

Comment: There isnt `scheme` in `dbListTables`. There is only `schema`...

Comment: see `?dbListFields(` for columns... better not ask two question in one

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it on my mind than! Everything is working now :)